# How to disable automatic line break on base constructor call

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My classes are formatted like this automatically in Visual Studio.

```
[Serializable]
public class TestException : Exception {
    public TestException()
        : base() {
    }
}
```

I do not want that line break to happen between constructor and base constructor call, so it should look like this.

```
[Serializable]
public class TestException : Exception {
    public TestException() : base() {
    }
}
```

What settings would I have to change in order to achieve my expected result?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no such setting in the Visual Studio's built-in `Options\Text Editor\C#\Formatting\New Lines` dialog.

If you use ReSharper there is a `Place constructor initializer on same line` option under `Code Editing\C#\Formatting Style\Line Breaks and Wrapping`:

[image: ReSharper]

Comment: Dammit! One of few things that hinders VS from being perfect.

Comment: I actually have this checked, and it looks like yours does in the preview, but it still moves the base() call to a new line. Weird.

Comment: Same issue here. Has it ever got fixed?

Comment: @frostshoxx, This problem has existed since at least R# 5 and JetBrians seem unable to fix it (https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/304885). It still affects me now with R# 9. I had to turn off CodeMaid's excellent format on save feature due to this bug.