# Disable code formatting for specific block of code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

How can I **disable code formatting** for a specific block of code in **Visual Studio 2017** (C# 7)?

I have this method:

```cs
public CarViewModel(ICarsRepo carsRepo)
{
    ...

    Manufacturers = ToSelectList<Manufacturer>();
    Categories = ToSelectList<Category>();
    States = ToSelectList<State>();
}
```

And I would like to format it like so:

```cs
public CarViewModel(ICarsRepo carsRepo)
{
    ...

    Manufacturers   = ToSelectList<Manufacturer>();
    Categories      = ToSelectList<Category>();
    States          = ToSelectList<State>();
}
```

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd>, it goes back to what it was.

#### `#region` inspiration

I would like something to wrap the specific block of code like a `#region`:

```cs
public CarViewModel(ICarsRepo carsRepo)
{
    ...

    #region disable_format

    Manufacturers   = ToSelectList<Manufacturer>();
    Categories      = ToSelectList<Category>();
    States          = ToSelectList<State>();

    #endregion
}
```

#### `#pragma` inspiration

Or not necessarily a `region`, maybe a `pragma` used like in this code snippet:

```cs
            var parameter = 0;
            var sqlCommand = $"{parameter}";
#pragma warning disable EF1000 // Possible SQL injection vulnerability.
            this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand);
#pragma warning restore EF1000 // Possible SQL injection vulnerability.
```

This is more of an aesthetic preference which might not be shared by most developers, but which I quite like in my code from time to time.

Answer (score 26):

- **Visual Studio** ([reference](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36930#issuecomment-530441099))

  - To disable formatting: `#pragma warning disable format`
  - To enable formatting: `#pragma warning restore format`

  ```cs
      switch (number) {
  #pragma warning disable format
          case 1:    cardinal = "one";     animal = "monkey";     break;
          case 2:    cardinal = "two";     animal = "horse";      break;
          case 3:    cardinal = "three";   animal = "pig";        break;
          case 4:    cardinal = "four";    animal = "chicken";    break;
  #pragma warning restore format
      }
  ```
- **Rider** ([doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Configure_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#using-comments-to-configure-formatter))

  - To disable formatting: `// @formatter:off`
  - To enable formatting: `// @formatter:on`

  ```cs
      switch (number) {
          // @formatter:off
          case 1:    cardinal = "one";     animal = "monkey";     break;
          case 2:    cardinal = "two";     animal = "horse";      break;
          case 3:    cardinal = "three";   animal = "pig";        break;
          case 4:    cardinal = "four";    animal = "chicken";    break;
          // @formatter:on
      }
  ```
- **Combined**

  ```cs
      switch (number) {
  #pragma warning disable format // @formatter:off
          case 1:    cardinal = "one";     animal = "monkey";     break;
          case 2:    cardinal = "two";     animal = "horse";      break;
          case 3:    cardinal = "three";   animal = "pig";        break;
          case 4:    cardinal = "four";    animal = "chicken";    break;
  #pragma warning restore format // @formatter:on
      }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

This matches your need. Not just C#, but also for ANY language.

```cs
Manufacturers/**/= ToSelectList<Manufacturer>();
Categories/*   */= ToSelectList<Category>();
States/*       */= ToSelectList<State>();
```

Comment: Not that it needs to, but I can't see how that works for VB, even substituting " ' ' " for " /* */ ".

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't disable just a block of formatting but it stops Visual Studio from formatting any of your declaration statements.

[image]