Disable Visual Studio 2022 format document delete spaces in function parameters in C#
Before Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D

After Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D

I want when I press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D, my document will keep style like image 1. But I can't find any options in the settings. I checked the "Ignore spaces in declaration statements" option but it doesn't work.

Go to: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Spaces and play around with it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083158/5045688

@MHMD I have tried all the options but none of them work for this case

@AlexanderPetrov Those are unofficial ways, but they are also temporary solutions
